# Incorrect deserialisation of a generic list using ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#, json, servicestack-text, servicestack-bsd

I'd like to ask if the following behaviour I get - with either v3 (BSD) or v4 - is a bug.

I have a generic list. I serialise it using myList.ToJson(). As a result I get this:

```
"[{\"__type\":\"MyNameSpace.MyType, MyAssembly\", ... (properties)},
{... (properties)},
{... (properties)},
{... (properties)},
...]"
```

That is, only the first element has its type written. As a result, when I do this:

```
var deserialised = myList.ToJson().FromJson<List<object>>();
```

I get a list that has as its first element a MyType and as subsequent elements strings. I know that:

```
FromJson<List<MyType>>()
```

works but I don't know the type at compile time. I have two questions:

1. Is this a bug?
2. If not, is there a way I can work around it without the overhead of dynamic parsing (i.e. JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo)?

The reason for the above is:

```
JsState.IsWritingDynamic = false;
```

at:

```
        if (WriteTypeInfo != null || JsState.IsWritingDynamic)
        {
            if (JsConfig.PreferInterfaces && TryWriteSelfType(writer)) i++;
            else if (TryWriteTypeInfo(writer, value)) i++;
            JsState.IsWritingDynamic = false;
        }
```

in:

```
WriteType<T, TSerializer>.WriteProperties
```

That line was added at 067ce1f62fc6addd3685a2134dd576529db2549f on 9.12.2012 to remove the types of properties themselves. I think that the previous value of IsWritingDynamic should be restored after the writing of all properties, that is, before the end of that same method.
Could anyone please confirm this?